# How to find 3 level of 2 level .name domain?

Tags: domains, registration, name

I want buy .name domain, WHOIS said that it's free, but registrator canceled registration and said that there maybe 3-rd level domain and i cant buy eg. aaaaaa.name if there already registred bbbbbb.aaaaaa.name

But how can i find ths domain? Maybe it will be free soon?
I tried find it with google and other search machines

Comment: What registrar are you using?

Comment: 2domains,but another said  same thing

Comment: Try using more registrars or posting on SysAdmin. They might have better insight into DNS/Domain issues. Though make sure you re-word it so it won't get thrown back here.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name)

> Domains may be registered on the second level (john.name) and the
>   third level (john.doe.name). It is also possible to register an e-mail
>   address of the form john@doe.name. Such an e-mail address is a
>   forwarding account, and requires another e-mail address as the
>   recipient address.
>
> When a domain is registered on the third level (john.doe.name), the
>   second level (doe.name in this case) is shared, and may not be
>   registered by any individual. Other second level domains like
>   johndoe.name remain unaffected.
>
> When the name TLD was first launched, only third-level registrations
>   (and forwarded e-mail addresses) were available. In January 2004,
>   second-level registrations became available. The original intended
>   structure of domain names was first.last.name, so that an individual
>   could get a domain corresponding to his or her actual name.

You can also use the [official .name WHOIS tool](https://whois.nic.name/DotNameWhois/pages/Query.jspx) to check whether your 2nd level domain is available.